# Is there way to download all Java EE interfaces?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

If I wanted to develop my own implementation of Java EE platform. I would have to implement all interfaces which provides the platform. Where can I download the source code for all interfaces? (I understand that I can restore them yourself for Java EE api, or I can just download the source of tomcat).

How should this be done correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build your own implementation of Java EE, you wouldn't just read the interfaces as they convey only a tiny bit of information. The first place would be to read the specification at http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316

Note that this in an *umbrella* specification, which covers over a dozen of other specifications, e.g. the ones for JSF at http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314, Servlet at http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315, JPA at http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317 etc etc.

The reference implementation of Java EE 6 (the current version), lists the Maven coordinates of the official API jars. Those are the interfaces with stripped bodies (meaning you can compile against them and read them, but can't deploy them): See http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2-final.html

One of the Java EE spec leads has posted a table with some pointers to Maven coordinates of individual parts of Java EE, see: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2011/09/02/jcpjavaee-artifacts-maven-central?force=441 (this might also give you a better impression of the breadth of what needs to be implemented).

Finally, note that Tomcat implements only a very small subset of Java EE, namely Servlet, JSP and JNDI. It would be a start to look at Tomcat's source for sure, but you have to realize it's not even close to a full Java EE 6 implementation.

Good luck!

Comment: Arjan Tijms! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I have a question and it is why you want to do this? Java EE has a lot of modules and frameworks,
but you can make a maven project and add Java EE modules dependency in your pom xml file,

for example your pom may be like this :

```
......
......
<dependencies>
    ......
    ......
    <dependency>
        <groupId>geronimo</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
     </dependency>
     ......
     ......
</dependencies>
```

and download it's documentation and sources using maven
search your modules in this [site](http://mvnrepository.com/) and add them to your pom's dependency tag

Comment: I don't want to do this, I just want to know how it must be done carrectly. I just can't understand: why it's so hard to download all interfaces?

Comment: all interfaces? what do you mean? which?

Comment: sample: where i can find HttpServletRequest.java file?

Comment: maven has the benefit that you can download your modules by only insert a dependency tag in your pom xml file,search the internet with your file name or class and maven dependency for example your file is in this module  http://www.mkyong.com/maven/get-httpservletrequest-via-maven-repository/

Answer (score 0):

You can download all the JDK source code from [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/jrl_download.html).

Comment: j2se jdk does not contain j2ee implementation.